# Proving bound on the solution of a first order linear ODE.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given,

$d’ + fd = -E$, where $|E(t)|\leq e^{-\delta t}$, $\delta >0$.

$0<c_0<f(t)<C_0$ for all time $t>0$.

Prove that 
$|d|<e^{-\delta t}, \forall\ t>t_0,$ for some $t_0$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Have you tried applying [Grönwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality) to [variation of constants formula](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Variation_of_constants)?

Comment: @user539887 I cannot get it to work since Grönwall’s has the function in the integral as well. Here there will be no d in the integral in the solution formula obtained by variation of constants formula.

Comment: It can be done directly. Just multiply both sides of the equation by $\exp{F(t)}$, where $F(t)=\int\limits_{t_0}^{t}f(s)\,ds$ and $t_0>0$ is a fixed time moment ($t_0=1$ will do).

Comment: I doubt the above is true unless you add more conditions. The decay conditions on the unforced equation will have terms related to $c_0,C_0$ which are unrelated to $\delta$. Try solving the above with $E(t) = -e^{-\delta t}$ and $f=1$.

Comment: @copper.hat Right! Probably there is a typo in the paper. However, final result they need is exponential decay of d, which can be proven.